# using full-screen mode with feh in dwm

Tags: dwm, fullscreen, feh

When I try to run `feh -F <images>` in `dwm`, I do not have the ability to interact with the full-screen window via the keyboard; e.g., if I try to exit (`q`), nothing happens and the following is sent to stderr: `feh WARNING: Window Manager does not support MWM hints. To get a borderless window I have to bypass your wm`. This problem [has been observed by others](https://lists.suckless.org/dwm/0709/3475.html). It does not matter whether I am in monocle, floating, or tiling mode. I can still communicate with `feh` through the mouse (e.g., click to advance image, right click to exit). Is there a way to avoid this problem?

I am using `feh` v. 2.18, `dwm`  v. 6.1, and `debian` v. 9.2.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a long-standing [bug](https://github.com/derf/feh/issues/162) in `feh`. In accord with the bug report, I circumvented the problem by doing the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rxvt-unicode
$ echo "alias feh='urxvt -e feh'" >> ~/.bashrc
```